# C version of OpenSSL EVP_BytesToKey method

Tags: c, openssl, sha512

I'm looking for C implementation of the OpenSSL `EVP_BytesToKey` function.

This is pseudo-code explanation of the EVP_BytesToKey method (in /doc/ssleay.txt of the OpenSSL source):

```
/* M[] is an array of message digests
 * MD() is the message digest function */
M[0]=MD(data . salt);
for (i=1; i<count; i++) M[0]=MD(M[0]);

i=1
while (data still needed for key and iv)
{
    M[i]=MD(M[i-1] . data . salt);
    for (i=1; i<count; i++) M[i]=MD(M[i]);
    i++;
}

If the salt is NULL, it is not used.
The digests are concatenated together.
M = M[0] . M[1] . M[2] .......
```

this is my code(MD() is sha512. And i need the key is 32 bytes and the iv is 16 bytes)：

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long out[8]; 
    unsigned char key[9] = {0x4b,0x0c,0x0c,0x0c,0x0c,0x0c,0x0c,0x0c,0x0c};
    int len, i;

    len = sizeof(key);
    sha512(out, key, len);

    unsigned char a[sizeof(out)];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        long2char(out, a); // unsigned long long to unsigned char;
        sha512(out, a, sizeof(out));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After `count` times `sha512()`, the out is 64 bytes, so I think I don't need the rest of that pseudo-code. But the result is not correct， I don't know what went wrong.

I wish you can help me to figure it out.  thanks!

Comment: OpenSSL's EVP_BytesToKey uses MD5?   cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc();digest = EVP_sha512();EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, digest, salt, password, password_len, rounds, key, iv);  But here is EVP_sha512();  So I am confused!

Comment: first,I want to thank you for answer my question. In my case, what I want to do is use C to implement this step “EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha512(), salt, password, password_len, rounds, key, iv); ”. I found the cipher "EVP_aes_256_cbc()" is not important here, but the digest "EVP_sha512()" is. And I haven't call the PEM_Read or PEM_Write gear. So I use sha512 algorithm to hash the password and salt. But the total key and IV length is less than the digest length and final result is not correct. I don't know where is wrong. Please help me if you can,and I am very sorry to bother you

Comment: I will try the way :[http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/EVP_BytesToKey]`OPENSSL EVP BytesToKey` . thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for C implementation of the OpenSSL EVP_BytesToKey function...

Perhaps you should just use the one OpenSSL provides? You know, the one called `EVP_BytesToKey` in [`evp_key.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/evp_key.c) (shown below).

[OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both EVP_BytesToKey and commands like openssl enc

---

```
int EVP_BytesToKey(const EVP_CIPHER *type, const EVP_MD *md,
                   const unsigned char *salt, const unsigned char *data,
                   int datal, int count, unsigned char *key,
                   unsigned char *iv)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *c;
    unsigned char md_buf[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    int niv, nkey, addmd = 0;
    unsigned int mds = 0, i;
    int rv = 0;
    nkey = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(type);
    niv = EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(type);
    OPENSSL_assert(nkey <= EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
    OPENSSL_assert(niv <= EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);

    if (data == NULL)
        return nkey;

    c = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (c == NULL)
        goto err;
    for (;;) {
        if (!EVP_DigestInit_ex(c, md, NULL))
            goto err;
        if (addmd++)
            if (!EVP_DigestUpdate(c, &(md_buf[0]), mds))
                goto err;
        if (!EVP_DigestUpdate(c, data, datal))
            goto err;
        if (salt != NULL)
            if (!EVP_DigestUpdate(c, salt, PKCS5_SALT_LEN))
                goto err;
        if (!EVP_DigestFinal_ex(c, &(md_buf[0]), &mds))
            goto err;

        for (i = 1; i < (unsigned int)count; i++) {
            if (!EVP_DigestInit_ex(c, md, NULL))
                goto err;
            if (!EVP_DigestUpdate(c, &(md_buf[0]), mds))
                goto err;
            if (!EVP_DigestFinal_ex(c, &(md_buf[0]), &mds))
                goto err;
        }
        i = 0;
        if (nkey) {
            for (;;) {
                if (nkey == 0)
                    break;
                if (i == mds)
                    break;
                if (key != NULL)
                    *(key++) = md_buf[i];
                nkey--;
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (niv && (i != mds)) {
            for (;;) {
                if (niv == 0)
                    break;
                if (i == mds)
                    break;
                if (iv != NULL)
                    *(iv++) = md_buf[i];
                niv--;
                i++;
            }
        }
        if ((nkey == 0) && (niv == 0))
            break;
    }
    rv = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(type);
 err:
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(c);
    OPENSSL_cleanse(md_buf, sizeof(md_buf));
    return rv;
}
```